# CoreBluetooth APIMISUSE (send command - peripheral not connected)

Tags: iphone, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheralmanager

The system i'm working with uses the following scenario:

1. Connecting to bluetooth LE device
2. Discover Services & Characteristics
3. Write command to TX characteristic and receive response

Above works fine 90% of time. Now and then the system gets into a state where 3rd step constantly fails (there is no response from device whatsoever even though step 1 and 2 succeeded. Restarting the app / phone / BLE device DOES not remedy this. Block is constant. What does resolve the problem is manually unpairing the device from iOS system settings. Looking at BLE diagnostic logs i get this:

"pon. mar 7 21:27:30 Preferences[380]: [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE:  can only accept commands while in the connected state"

However prior to sending the commands i've debugged the app and i'm 100% the connection is established and services&characteristics have been discovered. Any Idea? Anybody facing similiar problems?

Answer (score 1):

Did you implement `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:` in your central manager delegate?

It will notify you when a peripheral disconnects. Could be that the peripheral disconnected or there was a connection error. You should always make sure to only do read/write operations while in the connected state.

Maybe also have a look at this method: `centralManager:didFailToConnectPeripheral:error:`

Comment: Actually i do both, additionallly i check for : CBPeripheralState state = self.dongleConnection.connectedDevice.peripheral.state;
    if (state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) before performing any read/writes from characteristic.